# How can we carry out merge sort of 8 elements with only 16 comparisons?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge

Well, I asked a question about sorting few days ago. I found out how to prove that the least number of comparisons by sorting 8 elements is 16 and I understood why. But my merge sort algorithm counts 17 comparisons and in my case it is right. To merge two sorted arrays with length x and y each we need (x+y)-1 comparisons, so in merge sort we get 17 comparisons. But it must be possible with 16 comparisons, so.. how? where can I save that 1 comparison).

Here is an image:

[image]

http://oeis.org/A001768

Thanks!

Comment: And this is that [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8673860/60761)

Comment: You state that you already know "how to prove that ... is 16". Your proof should be able to answer this question.

Comment: i mean i expect that theoretically it is possible

Comment: The "least" number of comparisons required to sort 8 elements with a merge sort is something less than 16. For example, if your two 4-element subarrays are `[0, 1, 2, 3]` and `[4, 5, 6, 7]`, then it will take only four comparisons to merge them. After the fourth comparison the first subarray is empty and you can just copy the second subarray--no item comparisons required.

Comment: Using radix sort or some other non-comparison sort algorithms you won't need to compare anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OP contains a clear proof that **merge sort** of 8 elements is not possible with less than 17 comparisons. Still it is possible to sort 8 elements in 16 comparisons with other algorithm. The algorithm is described in D.Knuth's "The art of computer programming", Vol 3, chapter 5.3.1. It is named **merge insertion**.

Lowest number of comparisons does not make this algorithm the fastest one. For example, [**Batcher odd–even mergesort**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batcher_odd%E2%80%93even_mergesort) with 19 comparisons easily outperforms **merge insertion** because it performs most comparisons in parallel.

Comment: very best answer.. there is a whole paragraph for my problem with 
"the best worst case" for number of comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

You can only get the least solution when you have an odd amount of numbers to sort.

Comment: How so? It's not obvious to me.

Comment: Because at the lowest level you save a comparison. Your base would be like 2 - 2 - 2 - 1 with 7 elements. Thus you will not need to compare the last couple (since it isn't a couple).

Answer (score 1):

You could prove that 16 comparisons is not enough by trying all possible algorithms. You would need and "algorithm generating algorithm" for this.