# What is the best sorting algorithm when user input is needed for comparisons?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am trying to come up with the best sorting algorithm when the actual comparison count is not a concern but how to compare is not known by the computer, thus needing user input.

For example let's say there is an array of foods, `[apple, banana, orange, pear]` and we want to sort it from the best to the worst. To know if *apple* or *banana* is better the user needs to answer it. However, if we know *apple* is better than *banana* and *banana* is better than *orange* (=user already provided input for those comparisons), then no input is necessary to compare *apple* and *orange*.

What kind of sorting algorithm can be used to minimize the times we ask the user for an input?

**Edits for clarification:**

(I read all the comments and realized I hadn't done a good job of explaining my question.)

Let's continue with the example above:

- There is a list of size n containing fruits.
- We are trying to sort the list from the user's most favorite fruit to the least.
- There are no duplicate fruits and the preference is transitive (A>B & B>C implies A>C)
- The user has a strong preference. (Either A>B or B>A)
- At first, we don't know anything about the user's preference and we can only learn about it by showing them 2 fruits and asking which one they prefer. We don't care about how many comparisons the computer does (it can even do *selection sort*) but we are trying to minimize the number of questions we ask the user.

The worst case scenario is asking **(n!/(2(n-2)!))** questions as it is the number of pairs and the best case is (getting lucky) and asking **(n-1)** questions.

What kind of algorithm can be used to minimize the number of questions asked to the user?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which sorting algorithm uses the fewest comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092548/which-sorting-algorithm-uses-the-fewest-comparisons)

Comment: @BobJarvis-СлаваУкраїні I don't think so because I already went through that question and the answers focused on the total number of comparisons.

Comment: See [sorting network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network#Optimal_sorting_networks). For example, given an array of 4 distinct elements, there are 6 pairs that can be compared, but an optimal sorting network can sort the array using only 5 comparisons. For an array of 12 elements, there are 66 pairs, but only 39 compares are needed.

Comment: That is a distinction without a difference. Fewest comparisons => least user input..

Comment: @user207421 There _is_ a tangible difference, which OP undortunately failed to articulate clearly. The total number of comparisons is of course `n log n`. The real question is "What is the minimal number of queries to the user?".

Comment: @user58697 There is no difference. The user gets one query per comparison to be done. That's because your comparison algorithm is "ask the user". Therefore queries asked and comparisons done are identical.

Comment: Since people seem confused, I should explain the other way as well. Write code that cleverly asks on the queries you need to. Replace "ask the user" with a call to any other comparison function you want. Voila - you now have created a sorting algorithm! And again queries = comparisons.

Comment: @btilly your assumption is that 2 elements are only compared ones, but for some sorting algorithms it is definitely not true (like bubble sort), and for faster ones like quicksort/merge/insertion - not obvious, but it looks like it is possible to compare the same 2 elements twice, also as soon as we can deduce relative ordering of 3 elements by asking 2 queries - we might still perform 3 comparisons during sorting, but only 2 queries, so optimal queries are less or equal comparisons

Comment: @IłyaBursov No such assumption exists. There is a one to one correspondence between calling a comparator, and asking a query to a human instead of a comparator. A sorting algorithm can make redundant comparisons, and we can ask redundant queries. A sorting algorithm can cleverly avoid redundant comparisons, and we can cleverly avoid redundant queries. They are the same.

Comment: As a practical matter, doing a lot of work to avoid a few comparisons is not usually worth it for a sorting algorithm. But that's just a question of what you're optimizing for. For sorting less than 47 elements, the Ford-Bellman sort, also called Merge-Insertion sort, will have the fewest comparisons of any known algorithm. If your data is likely to have sorted runs, then Timsort will do really well. And so on.

Comment: @user58697 Still not a difference. There is a trivial one to one correspondence between sorting algorithms that never call the comparator when the answer can be reasoned from transitivity, and sorting algorithms that never send a query to the user when the answer can be reasoned from transitivity.

Comment: Another way to say it is this.. You cannot optimize an algorithm that minimizes comparisons any further by finding comparisons that could have been skipped because of transitivity. Best really is best. If you can find a way to improve it, then it wasn't best.

Comment: @btilly There is a difference; I don't understand how you can't see it. The question clearly assumes transitivity. If a< b annd b < c are established, there is no need to ask a user about a and c. It is in fact a clasic problem stemming fron Charles Dodgeson (aka Lewis Carrol), but I am awaiting the confirmation from OP.

Comment: @btilly Still a difference. All comparisons are equal, but some of them are more equal. Let's think of the tennis tournament (Lewis Carrol problem). How many matches we need to deremine the sond best?

Comment: @user58697 If you write code for asking the human questions, and there will be a function call `query_human(a, b)`. It is a straightforward refactor to replace those calls with `compare(a, b)`. And the number of comparisons called will be identical to the number of queries made before.

Comment: With that, I'm done repeating what should be a trivial point. "Ask a human" is simply a kind of comparison. To minimize how many questions are asked, you write a sorting function that uses as few comparisons as possible. And then implement the comparison by implementing, "Ask a human." If you still can't understand that, then it is a waste of my time searching for the magic combination of words that will cause you to get it.

Comment: @btilly It is indeed straightforward. Just keep in mind that `query_human` is very very time consuming. Such refactoring  is a pessimisation. You keep disregarding transitivity.

Comment: @btilly there is no proven sorting function which 100% uses as few comparisons as theoretically possible, this is why as practical measure - it is possible to add some kind of cache to `ask_human` and thus reduce number of queries, of course this function will be called as many times as compare, but it will ask user less times it is actually called

Comment: @IłyaBursov Your cache cannot eliminate any comparison that the Ford-Bellman algorithm ever makes. And therefore you will not reduce the number of queries at all. And while it is true that no algorithm has been proven to be optimal, it is also true that nobody has ever beaten Ford-Bellman for arrays with less than 47 elements. This will be extremely hard to beat in practice.  And trying to take advantage of transitivity won't help.

Comment: @btilly probably you meant [Ford–Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge-insertion_sort) and for larger inputs (OP has no limit on N) it was already beaten in 1979, so merge-insertion with cache/transitivity/etc can help, at least we will be able to prove that no duplicate/trivial to deduce questions asked, thus - number of queries <= number of comparisons for currently known algorithms

Comment: @IłyaBursov Sorry, brain fart. I did mean Ford-Johnson. It already never asks a question with higher than 2/3 odds of any particular answer. Therefore it is just wishful thinking to hope that cache/transitivity can improve it.

Comment: @btilly I agree that these algorithms try to minimize comparisons and in many cases they will ask only minimal set of questions one per comparison, but lets consider contrived examples `[apple, banana, banana]` and `[banana, banana, banana]` - here we need at least 2 comparisons, but 1 or even 0 questions (with simple cache)

Comment: @IłyaBursov Those contrived examples are easily handled with a deduplication pass. If our list has entries like `[apple, pomme, grape]` and we need a human to tell us that `apple` and `pomme` are the same, well, a general purpose sorting algorithm already has to handle the case where there are duplicate elements. Your cache remains a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your comments, I realized the question was not specific enough and caused confusion so I edited it with clarifications.