# How to choose matchups in an ELO ratings system as matchups accumulate

Tags: sorting, ranking, rating, ranking-functions

I'm working on a crowdsourced app that will pit about 64 fictional strongmen/strongwomen from different franchises against one another and try and determine who the strongest is. (Think "Batman vs. Spiderman" writ large). Users will choose the winner of any given matchup between two at a time.

After researching many sorting algorithms, I found this fantastic [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164831/how-to-rank-a-million-images-with-a-crowdsourced-sort) outlining the ELO rating system, which seems absolutely perfect. I've read up on the system and understand both how to award/subtract points in a matchup and how to calculate the performance rating between any two characters based on past results.

What I can't seem to find is any efficient and sensible way to determine which two characters to pit against one another at a given time. Naturally it will start off randomly, but quickly points will accumulate or degrade. We can expect a lot of disagreement but also, if I design this correctly, a large amount of user participation.

So imagine you arrive at this feature after 50,000 votes have been cast. Given that we can expect all sorts of non-transitive results under the hood, and a fair amount of deviance from the performance ratings, is there a way to calculate which matchups I most need more data on? It doesn't seem as simple as choosing two adjacent characters in a sorted list with the closest scores, or just focusing at the top of the list.

With 64 entrants (and yes, I did consider and reject a bracket!), I'm not worried about recomputing the performance ratings after every matchup. I just don't know how to choose the next one, seeing as we'll be ignorant of each voter's biases and favorite characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amazing variation that you experience with multiplayer games is that different people with different ratings "queue up" at different times.

By the ELO system, ideally all players should be matched up with an available player with the closest score to them. Since, if I understand correctly, the 64 "players" in your game are always available, this combination leads to lack of variety, as optimal match ups will always be, well, optimal.

To resolve this, I suggest implementing a priority queue, based on when your "players" feel like playing again. For example, if one wants to take a long break, they may receive a low priority and be placed towards the end of the queue, meaning it will be a while before you see them again. If one wants to take a short break, maybe after about 10 matches, you'll see them in a match again.

This "desire" can be done randomly, and you can assign different characteristics to each character to skew this behaviour, such as, "winning against a higher ELO player will make it more likely that this player will play again sooner". From a game design perspective, these personalities would make the characters seem more interesting to me, making me want to stick around.

So here you have an ordered list of players who want to play. I can think of three approaches you might take for the actual matchmaking:

1. Peek at the first 5 players in the queue and pick the best match up
2. Match the first player with their best match in the next 4 players in the queue (presumably waited the longest so should be queued immediately, regardless of the fairness of the match up)
3. A combination of both, where if the person at the head of the list doesn't get picked, they'll increase in "entropy", which affects the ELO calculation making them more likely to get matched up

**Edit**
On an implementation perspective, I'd recommend using a delta list instead of an actual priority queue since players should be "promoted" as they wait.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid obvious winner vs looser situation you group the players in tiers.
Obviously, initially everybody will be in the same tier [0 - N1].
Then within the tier you make a rotational schedule so each two parties can "match" at least once.

However if you don't want to maintain schedule ...then always match with the party who participated in the least amount of "matches". If there are multiple of those make a random pick.

This way you ensure that everybody participates fairly the same amount of "matches".